# How to replace array element with respect to Index on another array

Tags: javascript

I have one array which contains values `array1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` and another array contains index of array1 and the value to be replaced `array2 = [[2,u],[3,x],[6,z]]`.

Now I want to replace value of array1 with respect to array2 please not array2 consist of `[array1_position, value_to_be_replaced]`

Now my new arra1 should look like this `array1 = [a,b,u,x,e,f,z]`.

I can do this with for loop but its again time consuming. what trick can i use to replace the value quickly. I am just learning about arrays and have a little knowledge on it.

Comment: You can't do this without using a for loop.

Comment: just as @Ramesh said, you will have to do a loop regardless of the syntax and even the language itself. That being said the best runtime complexity u can get is O(array2.length), and that is my looping through array2 items and making the needed changes from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any shorthand for such a verbose question.
Something on top of my mind is

```
array2.forEach((el) => {
  array1[el[0]] = el[1];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this

```
array2.forEach(arr => {
   const [index, replaced] = arr;
   array1[index] = replaced;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take fromEntries of the other array then just `map` it:

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
var array2 = [[2,'u'],[3,'x'],[6,'z']];
var d=Object.fromEntries(array2);
var result = array1.map((val, i)=> d[i] || val);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if my `array2 = [2,'u','xyz'],[3,'x'],[6,'z']` and I need to do the same thing.

Comment: @Mask, It won't work then beacuse `fromEntries` works on key value pair, so in your case it will discard the `xyz` and take `u` and then create object.

Answer (score 1):

With an ordered `array2` by indices, you could take a closure over an index of this array and map the values from eithe the first array or the replacements array.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    array2 = [[2, 'u'], [3, 'x'], [6, 'z']],
    result = array1.map(
        (j => (v, i) => i === array2[j][0] ? array2[j++][1] : v)
        (0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: if array1 is extremely larger than array2 then performance will suffer, its better to loop through array2 and modify array1 in place for best runtime/memory performance.